# How to create routes in node.js and include html code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am coming back here with some issues regarding Node.Js.
I am kind of new to Node, and I am trying to write some code to create a server and then, create some routes between pages.

In order to create the routes, do I have to convert the html file to hbs?

So basically, instead of the html tags, is there any possibility to include html pages, or files?

Also, for the CSS, do I need to do something or it should be included automatically?

I think that, in order to create a route between the pages, I need to check the URL?

Do I need separate file in which I am supposed to create some code for GET and POST methods? I am not really sure.

If I am using WebStorm and create a Node.Js Express project, it creates an folder 'bin' in which there is a file 'www'. What is this file?

Kind Regards,
G

```
//code for the server:

var http = require('http');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); // http header
    var url = req.url;

    if (url === '/'){
        res.write(`<h1>home page</h1>`); //write a response
        res.end(); //end the response
    } else if (url === '/index') {
        res.write('<h1>index page<h1>'); //write a response
        res.end(); //end the response
    } else if (url === '/test') {
        res.write('<h1>test page<h1>'); //write a response
        res.end(); //end the response
    } else if (url ==='/contact'){
        res.write('<h1>contact page<h1>'); //write a response
        res.end(); //end the response
    } else if (url ==='/about'){
        res.write('<h1>about page</h1>'); // write a response
        res.end(); //end the response
    }
}).listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`server start at portL ${port}`); //the server object listens on port 3000
});
```

Comment: Recently I've build a working example for `http.createServer`, have a look: https://github.com/ShaharShokrani/NodeJsSimpleWebServer/blob/master/server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that what you need is a rendering engine. You can use the [hbs npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs), which is a small and easy-to-use view engine based on [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com).

You need first to install **hbs**.

```
$ npm install hbs --save
```

Then make sure your folder structure is something like this:

```
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── server.js
└── views
    ├── about.hbs
    ├── contact.hbs
    └── home.hbs
```

And your **server.js** file, like this:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const hbs = require('hbs')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

// Configure view engine and set views folder

app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

// Manage the routes

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home')
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about')
})

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact')
})

// Start the server

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

This way, using the **hbs view engine**, you could also pass data from the server to your HTML content, like this:

```
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    const data = { name: 'John Doe' }
    res.render('about', data)
})
```

And following this example you would catch the data sent from the server at your  **/views/about.hbs** file, with something like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello, {{name}} how are you today?</h1>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

To reference CSS files you must create a **static directory** at your Node.js server. To do it add this to your **server.js** file:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then make sure you create a **/public** folder and move your assets there, something like this:

```
├── server.js
└── public
    ├── bundle.css
    └── logo.png
```

After that, you can now reference all your static content from your views. For example in your **home.hbs**:

```
<!-- Reference static CSS files -->
<link href="/public/bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Reference static images -->
<img src="/public/logo.png" alt="" />
```

If you don't want to use a view engine and just want to render a plain HTML file you can also do it:

```
app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/contact.html'));
});
```

Comment: I will have a look and try to convert my code. Thanks a lot for the information. Do you have, by any chance, a really helpful Node.Js tutorial? Kind regards :)

Comment: It does work with hbs, but I need somehow to include the CSS for the page.  Any Idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello again! I have used hbs as you told me and everything is working. The only thing is that some part of the CSS code is loading way to slow, or not even loading. Any idea?

Comment: I've edited my response, with how you can import CSS.